# Passing multiple argument to dbGetQuery()? with like operator

Tags: r, roracle

I am new to R coding. I have a question.

```
Df <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE ename like '%raju%'")
```

I want a more dynamic piece of code. when have multiple names such as deepak, ravi, raghu etc.

Comment: You didn't actually ask a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider dynamic concatenation with `paste0`. Outer `paste0` is to enclose larger string with needed quotes and `LIKE` operator:

```
likevars = paste0("LIKE '%", paste0(c("deepak", "ravi", "ragh"), 
                                    collapse="%' OR ename LIKE '%"), "%'")

Df <- dbGetQuery(con, sprintf("SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE ename %s", likevars))

# SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE ename LIKE '%deepak%' OR ename LIKE '%ravi%' OR ename LIKE '%ragh%'
```

Comment: Thank you Parfait for the solution it worked like charm